# Spark Prometheus metrics name contain random generated data?

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, grafana, metrics

Metric names that Spark 3.2.0 generates are as follows:

```
metrics_spark_a929f03bcd084dd08ffe5a3c9ba71018_driver_DAGScheduler_stage_waitingStages_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_spark_a929f03bcd084dd08ffe5a3c9ba71018_driver_DAGScheduler_messageProcessingTime_50thPercentile{type="timers"} 24749.0
```

I suspect that the part `a929f03bcd084dd08ffe5a3c9ba71018` is random generated. How can one write proper Grafana queries to match these metrics? Is it possible to configure Spark not to add these hashes into the metric names? Whare is the purpose for these random hashes in the metrics naming?

(Checked Spark's example `spark.metrics.conf` for 3.2.0, but found no option to configure this.)

Answer (score 4):

In Spark properties, you can specify following:

```
    "spark.metrics.namespace": "myapp"
```

So you will obtain:

```
metrics_myapp_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOffHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
```

[Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics)